# 2 Counts and combining the results as one column | sql server management studio

Tags: count, case, ssms

Im trying to do a count of distinct Id's of people in a database based on some registrationdate and creationdate.

```
tables:
 - people p
 - number n
 - message m
 - volume v
```

**Requirements**

- In case of a number linked to the Id;
  the time between the oldest number.registrationdatetime and message.creationdatetime <= 10 wd
- In case of a volume (and no number) linked to the Id;
  the time between the oldest number.registrationdatetime and message.creationdatetime <= 10 wd

Both should be counted in total as A

my count part of the query:

- count (case when datediff(dw, n.registrationdatetime , m.creationdatetime)  <=10 then p.id end as A
- ,count (case when datediff(dw, v.registrationdatetime , m.creationdatetime)  <=10 then p.id end as A

**my question**;

- How do I combine the 2 counts for a total that will be displayed in column "A"

Comment: Kindly provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: Oracle does not have a `DATEDIFF` function.

Comment: sorry i mean sql server management studio

Comment: @Maik_h821 add correspondent tag then